# QGIS 2.18 can't read multiple rasters in on geopackage

Tags: qgis, raster, geopackage

I'm trying to add multiple rasters in one geopackage

But QGis 2.18 seems to be unable to deal with...

To add the rasters I use GDAL commands :

```
gdal_translate -projwin 578000 6270000 580000 6268000 -a_srs EPSG:2154 -of GPKG -co RASTER_TABLE=image1 -co TILE_FORMAT=JPEG d:\donnees\ortho.ecw c:\temp\test.gpkg
gdal_translate -projwin 579000 6275000 581000 6273000 -a_srs EPSG:2154 -of GPKG -co RASTER_TABLE=image2 -co APPEND_SUBDATASET=YES -co TILE_FORMAT=JPEG d:\donnees\ortho.ecw c:\temp\test.gpkg
```

Everything seems ok

But when I try to open the raster from QGis, I get this dialog but then nothing happens...

[image]

If I add only each image in one geopackage, it is ok but I would like to put 2 images in one geopackage.

Comment: I can confirm that it doesn't work on QGIS 2.18.11, no matter what you select in die dialogue or how you select your raster layer. I reported this [as issue #16997](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/16997) to the QGIS bug tracker.